# Find reciprocal row duplicates

Tags: r, list

(Please feel free to change the title to something more appropriate)

I would like extract all reciprocal pairs from a asymmetric square matrix.

Some dummy data to clarify:

```
m <- matrix(c(NA,0,1,0,0,-1,NA,1,-1,0,1,1,NA,-1,-1,-1,1,0,NA,0,-1,1,0,0,NA), ncol=5, nrow=5)
colnames(m) <- letters[seq(ncol(m))]
rownames(m) <- letters[seq(nrow(m))]

require(reshape2)
m.m <- melt(m)  # get all pairs
m.m <- m.m[complete.cases(m.m),]  # remove NAs
```

How would I now extract all "reciprocal duplicates" from `m.m` (or directly from `m`)?

This is what I mean with reciprocal duplicate:

```
Var1 Var2 value
   b    a    0
   a    b   -1
```

And I would like to store each value combination, i.e. `{1,1},{-1,-1},{1,0},{-1,0},{0,0}` in a list with its Var combination `{a,b},{a,c},{a,d},{a,e},{b,c},{b,d},{b,e},{c,d},{c,e},{d,e}` pointing to it, something like

```
$`a,b`
[1] 0,-1
```

I haven't manage to solve this. Feel like it could be possible with `merge()` or `inner_join`. Also, I apologize for not providing the best example.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach based on the object `m.m`:

```
# extract the unique combinations
levs <- apply(m.m[-3], 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ","))

# create a list of values for these combinations
split(m.m$value, levs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the matrix representation, you can get vectors of each triangle of the matrix (which align as you wish) using:

```
m[upper.tri(m)]
t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
```

To name them:

```
nm <- matrix(paste("(",rep(rownames(m),times=nrow(m)), ",",rep(rownames(m),each=nrow(m)),")",sep=""), nrow=nrow(m))
nm[as.vector(upper.tri(m))]
```

Finally to convert to a list as you wish. First I put them in a new 2 x 10 matrix.  Then I used lapply to create the list structure.

```
pairs<- cbind(m[upper.tri(m)], t(m)[upper.tri(m)] )
rownames(pairs) <- nm[as.vector(upper.tri(m))]
pairs

m.list <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(pairs)),function(i) pairs[i,])
names(m.list) <- rownames(pairs)
m.list
```

Comment: Sweet solution! Thanks! :)